# Writing a executable (Win32) that registers for COM at startup and deregisters on termination

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I have a desire to write a Win32 executable (in C++) that performs all of its COM registration at startup so that its object(s) are then accessible via COM to client apps. When the executable terminates, it should then deregister with COM.
Is this kind of thing possible and if so, what are the steps involved?
I have been googling feverishly all afternoon without really finding any answers to this. Most solutions require up front registration (e.g. via a /register switch).
Thanks

Comment: This is the normal way that out-of-process servers work.  Well supported by ATL for example.

Comment: But is it? All examples I've seen require you to do a /regserver type thing ahead of time. Then you run the server and then your objects are accessible. I would like the registration/teardown to occur during the lifetime of the process, not separately. If I have missed an obvious googlable example of this behaviour then I apologise for my oversight.

Comment: The /regserver option is only required to allow a client to start the server.  It is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that [CoRegisterClassObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CoRevokeClassObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are the functions you are looking for. You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680076%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic in the COM server registering regardless of in-proc or out-of-proc. Registering means writing to the registry deregistering means deleting registry keys.

Usual EXE COM server read command line arguments to handle install/uninstall request and provide separate subroutines or execution paths but you can freely include the install/uninstall process in every execution.

```
WinMain()
{
  Install()
  CoRegisterClassObject();
  .. Message Loop ..
  CoRevoveClassOBject();
  Uninstall();
}
```